# Word2Vec: Any way to train model fastly?

Tags: orm, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I use `Gensim` `Word2Vec` to train word sets in my database.

I have about 400,000 phrase(Each phrase is short. Total 700MB) in my `PostgreSQL` database.

This is how I train these data using `Django ORM`:

```
post_vector_list = []
for post in Post.objects.all():
    post_vector = my_tokenizer(post.category.name)
    post_vector.extend(my_tokenizer(post.title))
    post_vector.extend(my_tokenizer(post.contents))
    post_vector_list.append(post_vector)
word2vec_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(post_vector_list, window=10, min_count=2, size=300)
```

But this job getting a lot of time and feels like not efficient.

Especially, creating `post_vector_list` part took a lot of time and space..

I want to improve speed of training but have no idea how to do.

Want to get your advices. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To optimize such code, you need to collect good information about where the time is spent.

Is most of the time spent preparing `post_vector_list`?

If so, you will want to make sure `my_tokenizer` (whose code is not shown) is as efficient as possible. You may want to try to minimize the number of `extend()`s and `append()`s that are done on large lists. You might have to even take a look at your DB's configuration or options to speed up the DB-to-Object mapping started inside `Post.objects.all()`.

Is most of the time spent in the call to `Word2Vec()`?

If so, other steps may help:

- ensure you're using gensim's Cython-optimized routines – if not, you should be seeing a logged warning (and training will be up to 100X slower)
- consider using a `workers=4` or `workers=8` optional argument to use more threads, if your machine has at least 4 or 8 CPU cores
- consider using a larger `min_count`, which speeds training somewhat (and since vectors for words where there are only a few examples typically aren't very good anyway, doesn't lose much and can even improve the quality of the surviving words)
- consider using a smaller `window`, since training takes longer for larger windows
- consider using a smaller `vector_size` (previously called `size`), since training takes longer for larger-size vectors
- consider using a more-aggressive (smaller) value for the optional `sample` argument, which randomly skips more of the most-frequent words. The default is `1e-04`, but values of `1e-05` or `1e-06` (especially on larger corpuses) can offer additional speedup, and even often improve the final vectors (by spending relatively less training time on words with an excess of usage examples)
- consider using a lower-than-default (5) value for the optional `epochs` parameter (previously called `iter`). (I wouldn't recommend this unless the corpus is very large – so it already has many redundant, equally-good examples of the same words throughout.)

Answer (score 1):

you could use a python generator instead of loading all the data into the list. Gensim works with python generators too. The code will look something like this

```
class Post_Vectors(object):
    def __init__(self, Post):
        self.Post = Post
    def __iter__(self):
        for post in Post.objects.all():
            post_vector = my_tokenizer(post.category.name)
            post_vector.extend(my_tokenizer(post.title))
            post_vector.extend(my_tokenizer(post.contents))
            yield post_vector

post_vectors = Post_Vectors(Post)
word2vec_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(post_vectors, window=10, min_count=2, size=300, workers=??)
```

For the gensim speedup, if you have a multi-core CPU, you could use the `workers` parameter. (By default it is 3)

Comment: This  sort of reading-via-generator can often be a good idea if the training examples can be read & constructed very quickly. However, if iterating over `Post.objects.all()` often involves database IO lag, and/or if `my_tokenizer()` is inefficient, and those things happen to be the main source of disappointing slowness, this approach could make things worse. The `Word2Vec()` will require, be default, 6 passes over the data, and this generator approach will thus repeat the DB/`my_tokenizer` delays 6 times (instead of the original once).

Comment: @AshutoshBaheti I tested it with 1000 of queryset using `%%timeit`, the result  using generator is 4 times slower than original one.

Comment: @user3595632 Then maybe the the IO is the bottleneck in this case and the `word2vec` isn't. Can you check the time for reading all contents of `Post.objects.all()` and the time of `word2vec` on a pre-loaded array separately?

Maybe changing the input from Database to some other format might help in that case.

Comment: I think that querying databases is bottleneck... I think I should keep using my one X)...

Comment: That explains why the generator one performed poorly